# How can i delete blogs just belonging to the current user that are in a blogs database?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin, blogs

I want to have a delete button underneath blogs entered just by the owner of the current profile, I have tried implementing a deleteMyBlog function but no joy so far. whats the best way to go about this?

Here is my view. I know I would need but some delete button here but I'm not sure how to fit around my current foreach loop:

```
  <?foreach($blogs AS $viewData):
  $delete = $viewData['id'];
 {
$id = $viewData->id;
$title = $viewData->title;
$body = $viewData->body;
$username = $viewData->username;
$date = $viewData->date;

?>

   <b> <?=$title?></b>
    <p><?=$body?></p>

      <p>posted by:<?=$username?></p>
      <p>date: <?=$date?></p>
   <?=anchor("blog/deleteMyBlog/$delete", 'delete')?>
<hr>

<?
}
?>
```

My model:

```
class Blogmodel extends CI_Model
{
  public function __construct()
   {
    parent::__construct();
    } 

   function deleteMyBlog($id)
   {

    $this->db->where(array('id' => $id));
    $this->db->delete('blogs');

}

public function get_last_ten_entries()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('blogs', 10);
    return $query->result();

   }
public function insert_entry()
{
    $this->title = $this->input->post('title');
    $this->body = $this->input->post('text');
    $this->username = $this->session->userdata('username'); 
    $this->date = date("Y-m-d");

    $this->db->insert('blogs', $this);

   }
  }
```

Controller:

```
 class Blog extends CI_Controller {

public function _construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('Blogmodel','Blog'); 
    $this->load->model("profiles");

}


function deleteMyBlog($id) {

    $this->blogs->deleteBlog($id);

    redirect('blog');

}



public function index()
{

    $username = $this->session->userdata('username'); 

    $viewData['username'] = $username;

    $this->load->model('Blogmodel');


    if($this->input->post('act') =='create_post')
    {
        $this->Blogmodel->insert_entry();

    }


    $viewData['blogs'] = $this->Blogmodel->get_last_ten_entries();

    $this->load->view('shared/header');  
    $this->load->view('blog/blogtitle', $viewData);
    $this->load->view('shared/nav');
    $this->load->helper('form');// Load the form helper.

    // Lets set the stuff that will be getting pushed forward...
    $data = array();
    $data['form_open']=form_open();
    $data['form_title'] = form_input(array('name' => 'title'));
    $data['form_text'] = form_textarea(array('name' => 'text'));
    $data['form_hidden'] = form_hidden('act','create_post');
    $data['form_submit'] = form_submit('submit','Make Post');

    $this->load->view('blog/blogview');
    $this->load->view('blog/post', $data);



       $this->load->view('shared/footer');
    }


  }
```

Thanks again guys

Comment: I have made changes to my view for what I have attempted so far...I get this error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: `$query->result()` will return an object. use `$query->result_array()` if you want an array

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is with assigning username to a variable, then with the SQL statement.

`Delete from tbl where colname='$username'`

That's the way I would do it, other people might have different methods. So all respect to those who would use somethin different

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because of this bit:

```
<?foreach($blogs AS $viewData):
   $delete = $viewData['id'];
```

It should be this:

```
$delete = $viewData->id;
```

You're using the exact same data a line later correctly, why are you trying to use $viewData which is an object as an array here, but an object 2 lines later. Other than that the rest of what you're doing there should work fine but it is rather dangerous in practice. If I go to your site and type the url to that controller function with a blogId at the end that blog goes away, at no point are you checking that the user actually should be allowed to delete that blog. Obscurity != Security. Meaning that just because you think people won't find the link doesn't mean they won't.

Personally I save the userId of a logged in user to the session and save the session to the database. Then when I do anything to user records I do a check to ensure the user making the change has the authorization to make that change.

So your delete function would be something like this:

```
function deleteMyBlog($id)
{
    $this->db->where('username',$this->session->userdata('username');
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->delete('blogs');
}
```

Also you should be using userId's not usernames for saving to other tables, the indexes work better on numerical ID's as far as I know and it's less overall data in the tables. Saving userId 342 to your blogs table takes up less space than saving username bobsyouruncle3421.

For the record, I know this isn't part of the question but actually deleting things from the database has downsides. Not the least of which is screwing up the indexing and slowing down queries in the long run. A far better solution is adding a status or active column to any tables you may want to delete from and giving them a value of 1 for active and 0 for deleted. Then instead of actually deleting the item you change it's active column to 0. When displaying items you add a check for active = 1 to the display query.

This serves two purposes, first you don't mess up the indexing, the record is never removed just modified so the indexes remain intact. Second and nearly important is you never have the possibility of accidentally deleting something you didn't mean to delete, it is never really gone. So you could "undelete" anything at any time.

Comment: Thanks for that info Rick, now I have in fact tried the code you gave me and it doesnt seem to correspond with when I call the deleteMyblog function in my controller as I now get an error - Message: Undefined property: Blog::$Blogmodel. This is how I called it in the controller:function deleteMyBlog($id) {
   
  $this->Blogmodel->deleteMyBlog($id);
 
  redirect('blog');
   
 }

Comment: Make sure you're loading blogmodel first and the only place it should be capitalized is in the class name. So it should be $this->blogmodel->deleteMyBlog($id) that error is usually thrown when you don't load the model first though so $this->load->model('blogmodel');

Comment: I've done that in my model already...perhaps i should put it in the deleteMyBlog function?

Comment: Ahh I see the issue, you're trying to load blogmodel twice, once in the constructor with the alias blog and then again in the function itself. Take it out of one or the other, if you leave it in the constructor remember to call your functions with $this->blog->function() since you put the alias in there. Also again, lower case for everything but the class name in the blogmodel itself. In the delete function you're calling $this->blogs instead of $this->blog.